# Why is the enter key behaving like the tab key?

Tags: filemaker

I have a "search" layout, which has several object boxes for the user to type in search queries. I have `Set Tab Order...` which works great. However, rather confusingly, pressing `enter`/`return` also has the same effect as pressing `tab`.

I have looked in the `Inspector > Go to next object using` and see that both the `return` and `enter` are unchecked.

What/where else could be causing this behaviour? *Ideally I would like the `return`/`enter` key to perform a script/act like a button, is this possible?*

Note: I am in Find Mode.

Comment: As an aside: [The enter and return keys are different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key#Differences_between_Enter_and_Return).

Comment: Please don't preface your title with misspelled tags.  Our tagging system *works*.  Any user who cares about filemaker will find your question *because they are watching the filemaker tag*, not because you have prefaced your title with it.  For more information, please read [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) and [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61055/when-should-we-remove-pseudo-tags-from-a-title) on [meta].

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this. I have been putting Filemaker at the beginning of *all* my questions. I removed the *tabs* tag, which I thought you were talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no script trigger, try to double check that the enter/return is really off for the field in question. Maybe there are two or more fields stacked on top of each other (sometimes developers do that) and you checked the wrong one.

Comment: It was hidden behind another object! Thanks! To be honest I had thought that `Got to next object using` was a layout attribute rather than an object attribute. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I checked the fields and there were no hidden scripts, triggers, conditional formatting or anything like that; however, the fields were either a drop-down list or a drop-down calendar so after selecting the criteria, the cursor would go to the next field.

I noticed that if I enter the finding criteria and double click the same field (to avoid going to any other field) and then click the return or enter keys, it works. So stay in the field when you click return or enter and it will perform the find.

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive that you're in find mode when you're doing this? The default behavior in find mode is that the return key executes the find.

Comment: Something is weird/wrong - try creating a brand new file, or open a starter solution, and see what the behavior is.

Comment: You are right (the default behaviour is as you say), unfortunately I am using a database which someone else has created... I think the previous guy has been "tweaking" it. I want to *un*tweak it!

Comment: Try opening the script debugger and pressing the return key. If the script debugger kicks in, there is a script trigger that is intercepting the key event.

Answer (score 0):

If the field you've selected has a dropdown list then CLICKING ON IT ONCE will bring the list down but not place the cursor in the field. Selecting the field a second time will place the cursor in the field. Once the cursor is actually visible in the field you will find that the TAB key works as you expect.

Otherwise, with the dropdown list down and the cursor not in the field, the RETURN key will move to the next field when in Find mode. This default behaviour sort of makes sense to me because the RETURN key can't act on the field until the cursor is actually in the field.

I had the same problem as you and it stumped me for a while too.